# Jmeter writing the request details to CSV/XML from view result tree listener

Tags: java, xml, csv, jmeter

When we write data of view result tree listener to CSV/XML , it does not write all data like parameters used in request to CSV.

All the details are related to the response.How to get the the request details in the csv so that we can have one to one mapping of request and response and find out which request has failed.

Answer (score 10):

You can set the following properties to `true` so your results file will look like what you used to see in [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) Listener

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.url=true
jmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true
```

Above properties can be either set in *jmeter.properties* file or in *user.properties* file (both live under /bin folder of your JMeter installation) or passed as a command-line arguments if you run Jmeter in non-GUI mode as

```
jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.response_data=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.samplerData=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.requestHeaders=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.url=true -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.responseHeaders=true -n -t example.jmx -l example.jtl
```

Look for properties, containing "saveservice" in jmeter.properties file to see what else can be configured and into [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for ways of proper setting/overriding various JMeter Properties.

Comment: Hi my request is a JSON request and I want to write this request in the CSV file."Save Request Headers(XML)" will store it in a xml format.I want an csv output with request,response code(which I can get through listener).I cant find a way to write the "request".

Comment: I'm afraid that JSON structure can cause problems with CSV file and not every listener will be able to parse it.

Answer (score 1):

If you press on the "Configure" Button on the upper right side, you can specifiy, which data should be logged and which not.
Did you configured the Result Tree Listener to store those information?

[image: The Result Tree Listener]